# Sharing Visual Studio 2010 Code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Firstly, sorry if it has been asked before or seems a stupid question.
But I have played around with visual studio 2010, making a few forms click and handle together to do a function I desire, and now I have finished it, I need to take all that code and give it to someone. How do I do this? I even had a stab at writing the code manually in notepad, but then it wouldnt run how it did in the visual studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean give them the source, or deploy / install the result?

Comment: Try browsing to the Projects folder found in Documents and giving them the .sln file

Answer (score 1):

Share for which purpose?

To publish on a website? Use code highligthers/formatters available online.

To demonstrate a concept - a simple copy/paste into email may be enough.

To let other person run your app, the general approach is to delete `obj` and `bin` folders from all your project folders within a solution, and pack the rest into a zip archive.

Now that may not work, if you used any 3rd party libraries and another person does not have them. If you want a more specific answer, please narrow the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the form.designer.vb and the form.vb and paste them into notepad (plus) and save them as a text file, zip them and email them.

The receiver can then copy and paste them into a new project and it will build as the same project.

This is for simple for projects.

Some people prefer to change the file extensions (the executable files usually won't pass email scans), I, personally don't like this.

I also do this with all my code and email it to myself as an extra back up procedure.